# How to bind to page property in silverlight?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, silverlight, xaml

I have a silverlight page with a boolean property in the codebehind.

In the xaml I have a tabcontrol and inside  one of the tabitem's content is a busyindicator.

I want to bind the busyindicator's isbusy property to the boolean property in the codebehind, but I can't resolve it no matter what binding statement I use.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the codebehind, you need to make sure you have set the DataContext. So in the Load event of your page, put this:

```
this.DataContext = this;
```

If you have already done this then you will need to post more details.

Answer (score 6):

Slugster does have a neat solution but I think what you are looking for is this

```
<Page x:Name="MyPage>
<TabControl>
    <TabItem>
       <BusyIndicator IsBusy="{Binding ElementName=MyPage, Path=MyBooleanPropertyNameInCodeBehind}" /> 
    </TabItem>
</TabControl>
```

Answer (score 3):

Slugster and AntSlay, both of your solutions worked. I found that this works also:

```
<Page DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}">
    <TabControl>
        <TabItem>
           <BusyIndicator IsBusy="{Binding MyBooleanPropertyNameInCodeBehind}" /> 
        </TabItem>
    </TabControl>
</Page>
```

Answer (score 0):

I have something like this for a Label

```
   public string Caption { get; set; }

    void UserControl_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
       Caption = "Label";
    }
```

and in XAML

```
 <Label Content="Label" Height="28" Name="label1" DataContext="{Binding Caption}" />
```

I'm sure you can do the same thing with busy indicator.