# Bind EasingColorKeyFrame color Value

Tags: silverlight, binding, storyboard, windows-phone, windows-phone-8

I've got the following Windows Phone code which is used to change the color of a `Rectangle` from Black to Red.

```
<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot">
  <phone:Pivot x:Name="MyPivot" >
    <phone:PivotItem x:Name="MyPivotItem">
      <Canvas x:Name="MyCanvas">
        <Canvas.Resources>
          <Storyboard x:Name="MyStoryboard">
            <ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames
              Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Rectangle.Fill).(SolidColorBrush.Color)"
              AutoReverse="True">
                <EasingColorKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:0" Value="Black" />
                <EasingColorKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:0.5" Value="Red" />
            </ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
          </Storyboard>
        </Canvas.Resources>
      </Canvas>
    </phone:PivotItem>
  </phone:Pivot>
</Grid>
```

What I'd like to do is make this more dynamic so that I can change the colors used in the `EasingColorKeyFrame`s from the code-behind page. Is it possible to bind the `Value` of my `EasingColorKeyFrame`s to a property in my code-behind page?

Comment: Aren`t you trying to bind to properties of Grid named 'LayoutRoot' that doesn`t have your color properties? In the article author makes binding to UserControl itself, not Grid.

Comment: ah, you are correct. I think I misunderstood that the first time through but reading it again it seems more clear, I'll remove it from the question. Do you know of a way I can bind a property from my code-behind page then?

Comment: The answer on this question by @AntSlay looks similar to what I tried before but uses the Page name instead of LayoutRoot: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5130937/how-to-bind-to-page-property-in-silverlight. I will give this a try tonight!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're just trying to change the colors from a code-behind page then just give your frames an x:Name and set their values in the code behind.

```
...
<EasingColorKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:0" x:Name="start" Value="Black" />
<EasingColorKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:0.5" x:Name="end" Value="Red" />
...
```

Code-behind:

```
private void ChangeColors()
{
  start.Value = Colors.Green;
  end.Value = Colors.Blue;
}
```

Comment: oh wow. I'm not sure how I hadn't though of that, but thank you. That would definitely be the simplest solution. I'll try this out tonight!